# Why a wave equation can be strongly affected by weak gravitational fields?

Tags: general-relativity, field-theory

Suppose a massless scalar field in a curved spacetime propagates as $$(g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\mu\partial \nu-\xi R)   \psi=0 $$ with $\xi =0$ or $R=0$ for Schwarzschild metrics.

Suppose the gravitational field is weak, and $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}+\epsilon \gamma_{\mu\nu}$ where $\epsilon$ is the perturbation parameter. And let the scalar field be $\psi=A e^{ik(x0-x3)}$.

Then the wave equation can be solved up to the first order of $\epsilon$, giving $$2ik\partial_3 A-\nabla ^2 A+\epsilon [-\frac k 2 (2k(\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{33})+i(\partial_3 \gamma_{00}-\partial_3 \gamma_{11}-\partial_3 \gamma_{22}+\partial_3 \gamma_{33}+2\partial_2 \gamma_{23}+2\partial_1 \gamma_{13}))A+\cdots] =0$$ where terms with the derivatives of $A$ is omitted.

I note that there are $k^2$ inside the perturbation terms for $A$. For a light with wavelength of $1000 ~\rm{nm}$, $k$ will be about $6 \times 10^6$. The metric for the earth will let $\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{33}$ be about $   \frac {mz^2}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \approx 1.4\times 10^{-9}$ for $x=y=0, z=6.37\times10^6$ is the radius of the earth, $m=8.87\times 10^{-3}$ is the Schwarzschild radius of earth.

Hence it appears that the perturbation for $A$ is quite strong even in a weak gravitational field. But this should be wrong. But where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Note that your value of $k$ isn't $6 \times 10^6$;  it's $6 \times 10^6 \text{ m}^{-1}$.  It doesn't make sense to talk about a dimensionful quantity being "large", since its numerical value is dependent on the units you use.   I suspect that the correct comparison is between $k$ and the (inverse) length scale of the variations in $\gamma_{\mu \nu}$, which arises from the $\partial_\rho \gamma_{\mu \nu}$ terms.  The $k$ terms are still quite large compared to those, though, and I think there's more going on than just unit mix-ups.

Comment: Hi, @MichaelSeifert . Thank you for your comment. But I could not understand your post well. I use the natural units with $c=1$. Both sides of the equation have the dimension of $[L^{-2}]$. Hence I throw the units of $m^{-2}$ from both sides. Then the factor in $-k^2( \gamma_{00}+\gamma_{33} )A$ is quite large.